# detecting Android gestures of alphabets using gesture overlay

Tags: java, android, gesture, gesture-recognition, android-gesture

I am developing an application in which English alphabet will be written in gestures format and those alphabets will be written in the text view, but my problem is my app is not detecting the gestures correctly even I have different gestures for the same word.. Is there any file available on the internet for gestures? which I can add in the project? or is there any other way to make the gesture detection accurate?
Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using different styles for your each word will make your gesture detection accurate.